# Switching between <div> elements using buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, css

I have a specific goal in mind.

Please reference this page: http://cubancomplex.kodingen.com/test/MM/dashboard1.html

On the very bottom right, there is a `<div>` with two buttons on each side. The `<div>` currently has one google chart contained inside.

The goal is for a user to be able to use those two buttons to switch between charts for approximately eight cities.

I am not familiar with javascript or jQuery so I would appreciate any assistance! How should I go about achieving this?

Here is the code for that section:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="markerNavLeft" title="Prev" id="prevMarker">&lsaquo;</div>
    <div id="markers">
        <div id="chart">
            <div id="auckland_chart_div"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="markerNavRight" title="Next" id="nextMarker">&rsaquo;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't mean to be rude, but if you don't know javascript/jquery at all then you need to learn it. Try things. Come back with specific questions if you have any. Otherwise you just asking people to do your job for you.

Comment: i respect your point of view, but in my defense i *AM* learning. if you could point me to a place where it discusses how to accomplish something like this then by all means! The purpose is to learn and I thought people here are interested in helping.

Comment: Inside the page itself as a hidden div. I use Google Charts API which allows me to create the chart and populate it on the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, there's 2 option that you can use..

1. you can place your charts in your div id="chart". The first one add a class to mark it as a selected one (e.g. selected), of course the other is hidden… Please add a same class for all of the chart(e.g. chart-detail). Then, you can use 
   `var temp = $(".selected").next(".chart-detail"); $(".selected").removeClass("selected"); temp.addClass("selected");`
   for the previous button, you can use .previous function.
2. You can use ajax ( .ajax function or .load function). Mark each chart with an ID so, you know what's the next or previous chart (within php).

Comment: thanks so much bobby! i will look into trying your first suggestion!